# Scraping a table

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the properties of a house and the corresponding values. I am interested in getting {key:{Property type: Commercial property, Purchase price: CHF 475,000, etc. }

I was able to extract the values one by one but not as a loop that is updating my dictionary.

```
<dl class="row xsmall-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-4 attributes-grid">
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Property type
        </dt>
        <dd>
Commercial property            </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Purchase price
        </dt>
        <dd>
CHF 475,000            </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Floor space
        </dt>
        <dd>
114 m&sup2;            </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Floor 
        </dt>
        <dd>
1. floor             </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Year of construction
        </dt>
        <dd>
1989            </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Balcony/ies
        </dt>
        <dd>
                <i class="fa fa-check text-green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Indoor parking 
        </dt>
        <dd>
                <i class="fa fa-check text-green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Outdoor parking
        </dt>
        <dd>
                <i class="fa fa-check text-green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Lift
        </dt>
        <dd>
                <i class="fa fa-check text-green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Cable TV
        </dt>
        <dd>
                <i class="fa fa-check text-green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Public transport stop
        </dt>
        <dd>
150 m            </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Motorway
        </dt>
        <dd>
500 m            </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <dt class="label-text">
            Shops
        </dt>
        <dd>
300 m            </dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: What have you accomplished before ask your question? Give us your code snippet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the html text provided by you, which is stored as a string in `table_text`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(table_text,"lxml")
temp_dict = {}
for d in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"column"}):
    temp_dict[d.find("dt").text.strip()] = d.find("dd").text.strip()
print(temp_dict)
```

I am guessing the html text you provided was for only one row of the table, if you want this for all the rows, loop over them and keep a parent dictionary where you update row as a key and temp_dict as a value in each iteration. This will give you the structure you wanted.